# Can not read variables from netCDF file

Tags: python, jupyter, literals, netcdf

I am trying to read some variables from netCDF4 aka `.nc4` files using Jupyter Notebook. There are three variables that I can read, but one variable that cannot be read.

I am getting an error  `"invalid literal for int() with base 10"` in `py2.7`

The same code is working with `py3.6` as all four variables can be read from the file.

Comment: Can you share the output of ncdump of your data i.e. `ncdump -h your_file`?

Comment: Can you share the code which is throwing the error?